# Multiple delete statements in SQL Task in SSIS. All except 2 are not executing

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, ssis

I have written multiple *DELETE* statements in a sql task in SSIS which are shown below. These statements are all executing except the 2 statements which does not seem to be executing but when i execute the statements using SQL management studio, it executes all the statements but in SSIS, it does not work. Statement number 2 and 3 does not work but the rest are working fine. Can anyone please suggest me whats wrong with my statements or logic?

Update: By the way all these statements are inside a SSIS Transaction using DTC method.

```
DELETE FROM [dbo].[RETAILTRANSACTIONDISCOUNTTRANS]      
WHERE SOURCESYSTEM  = 'CG' AND TRANSACTIONID IN (SELECT TRANSACTIONID FROM 
RETAILTRANSACTIONTABLE WHERE ERRORFLAG = 0 AND SOURCESYSTEM = 'CG')
```

Comment: In your WHERE clause IN sub query could you try adding a table hint to ADRM_RETAILTRANSACTIONTABLE_STG?... So SELECT TRANSACTIONID FROM ADRM_RETAILTRANSACTIONTABLE_STG WITH (NOLOCK)

Comment: Do you have active triggers on those two tables ?

Comment: I have added table hint as well but no luck. Could you please help.

Comment: [dbo].[ADRM_RETAILTRANSACTIONTABLE_STG] being deleted before it should be?

Comment: @Bogdan: No triggers on these two tables. I am banging my head into wall. Dont know whats wrong with the query.

Comment: There no terminating (like  ; or go) statement in between statements    , Most likely reason is transition are not getting committed .  Note SSMS automatically terminating ...

Comment: yeah looks like it is deleting before it should be

Comment: I have used semi colon too as well as separated the transactions in different SQL tasks still line 2 & 3 not executing

Comment: @Jessica: First option: Use SQL Profiler to intercept following events: SQL: BatchStarting, SQL:StmtStaring and from section Errors and Warnings: ErrorLog, EventLog, Exception and User Error Message. Start this trace, start that SQL task and then check if there is any *error * intercepted by SQL Profiler. **Warning: don't do this on prod !** StmtStarting events are very expensive. Also, within this trace, try to define filters on database name column. The second option is to configure OnError *property* for SQL tasks to FailComponent (I assume that is configure to Ignore).

Comment: I have tried creating a stored procedure and also used semicolon and go statements but no luck. When the query is executed at Management Studio it executes fine but when it executes in SSIS SQL task it does not work as expected.

Comment: Do you have 1 Execute SQL Task per delete statement in your SSIS project? And do you have Precedence Constraints set to Success and Completion between every task?